# C# - XAML doesnt re-binding the changes

Tags: c#, xaml

I am working on a small project..a game, but in the beggining was only console game, so decided to make it with UI using xaml..And here i have this problem - everythink seems to work fine except that it doesnt re-binding the changes i make.I have BaseModelView class which inherits INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            var propertyChangedArg = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, propertyChangedArg);
        }
    }
}
```

and also for collections im using ObservableCollection, but it doesnt not re-binding the changes..

I think the problem comes from here, because i dont call the OnPropertyChanged on every property for each class, i call it for the whole class but dont know.. like that

```
public Player Player
{
    get { return this.player; }
    set
    {
        this.player = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Player");
    }
 }
```

here i will link the repo, anyway its not a hidden project its mean to be open source, and maybe can find the problem more easily - http://goo.gl/mFgCXI

I hope someone can help me, because im stucked for days and dont know how to fix it to move on..

Thanks.

Comment: That will only raise `OnPropertyChanged` when you change the actual player, but not when the properties on `Player` change

Comment: If you want an easy way to implement `PropertyChanged`, you may want to check this: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged (I'm not affiliated to Fody in any way, just recommending it)

Comment: Thanks for this, looks very usefull and yeah i thought that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw your code on Github. You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on ALL classes that will be binded to. Also each property that will be bound should raise the OnPropertyChanged notification.

I see that you have binded to the properties of the Monstor & Hero class but its properties (which are bound in the UI) do not raise the OnPropertyChanged Notification.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your binding mode TwoWay and test again.